# How to assign a special section to an independent sector on STM32 flash memory?

Tags: in-app-purchase, stm32

[image]

As you can see,STM32F4xx series memory map is like that.I am develop an IAP application, the boot firmware may be over 64KB size, so I use sector 0-4 to put boot firmware.Now I want to put version msg and verify msg so on to a sector which wouldn`t be erased, its a waste to put them to sector 5.I try to modify ld file using STM32CubeIDE in many ways iI know but failed, So is there anyone know how to put msg to sector 1-3?

Answer (score -1):

Changing boot address is an option:[STM32 boot address setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56896375/how-can-i-change-the-start-address-on-flash) .
For example you can set boot address as start address of sector 1 and you can save your parameters on sector 0.
Another solution is using a dummy boot loader which only checks a button etc. to decide jump to boot loader or main application. For example you can put dummy boot loader on sector 0, parameters can be placed on sector 1, the main boot loader can be placed on sector 2-3-4 and main application can be placed on any where rest of the flash memory.